# Apply a jitter-like procedure to a crosstab in R

Tags: r, pivot-table

Is there a way to apply something similar to `jitter()` for a frequency table while keeping the Total constant? I would need to generate many tables that would be similar to each other.

Imagine, for example, parallel forms of a test which would give a crosstab like this:

```
# frequency data.frame
twobytwo = data.frame(
    Test1 = c('T', 'T', 'F', 'F'),
    Test2 = c('T', 'F', 'T', 'F'),
    Frequency = c(42, 20, 17, 21)
)

# crosstab
tabdat <- xtabs(Frequency ~ Test1 + Test2, twobytwo)

tabdat
#      Test2
# Test1  F  T
#     F 21 17
#     T 20 42
```

How can I do some random (unsystematic) changes to the resulting table which would, for example, give a new table like this:

```
tabdat2
#      Test2
# Test1  F  T
#     F 27 21
#     T 13 39

tabdat3
#      Test2
# Test1  F  T
#     F 24 21
#     T 10 45
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw 3 values from `[-x, x]` at first, and the 4th value will be the opposite number of the sum of these 3 values to ensure that the total is the same. Then just add the 4 values to `tabdat`. You can use `replicate()` to evaluate this expression repeatedly and store the output in a list.

```r
set.seed(123)

replicate(n = 3, simplify = FALSE, {
  noise <- sample(-10:10, 3)
  tabdat + c(noise, -sum(noise))
})

# [[1]]
#      Test2
# Test1  F  T
#     F 25 20
#     T 28 27
# 
# [[2]]
#      Test2
# Test1  F  T
#     F 13 24
#     T 19 44
# 
# [[3]]
#      Test2
# Test1  F  T
#     F 21 20
#     T 14 45
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks [Darren Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10068985/darren-tsai)! Can this list be converted to an array, like you would have in a 3-way xtabs?

Comment: @striatum Of course! Just delete `simplify = FALSE`, or explicitly set `simplify = "array"`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again [Darren Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10068985/darren-tsai). One final, follow up: I am happy to open another question here, but what would be the best way to label that new dimension> For example, rather than something like `, , 1`, to have something like `, , t1` and with some proper label for dimension, similar to `Test1` and `Test2`. I could only find `provideDimnames()` function that can partly do the job.

Comment: @striatum maybe `dimnames(x)[[3]] <- paste0('t', 1:3)` where `x` is the output of `replicate()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that may give better results depending on what you mean by "similar".

First, start with the raw data (individual T and F values, not the counts):

```
> rawdat <- expand.grid(Test1=c('T','F'), Test2=c('T','F'))[
+   rep(1:4, c(42, 20, 17, 21)),
+ ]
```

And confirm that it gives the same table

```
> xtabs( ~ Test1 + Test2, rawdat)
     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 42 17
    F 20 21
```

Now one option is to sample from this data frame with replacement.  This will result in the same overall total and the values will be similar and show a similar relationship between Test1 and Test2:

```
> (wrep <- replicate(3, {
+   tmpdat <- rawdat[sample(nrow(rawdat), replace=TRUE),]
+   xtabs( ~ Test1 + Test2, tmpdat)
+ }))
, , 1

     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 41 15
    F 19 25

, , 2

     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 38 20
    F 18 24

, , 3

     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 39  9
    F 27 25
```

We can see that the overall total is the same each time, but the row and column totals vary.

```
> apply(wrep, 3, addmargins, simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
     Test2
Test1  T  F Sum
  T   41 15  56
  F   19 25  44
  Sum 60 40 100

[[2]]
     Test2
Test1  T  F Sum
  T   38 20  58
  F   18 24  42
  Sum 56 44 100

[[3]]
     Test2
Test1  T  F Sum
  T   39  9  48
  F   27 25  52
  Sum 66 34 100
```

We can also see that the relationship (e.g. odds-ratio) is similar

```
> apply(wrep, 3, function(x) fisher.test(x)$estimate)
[1] 3.547026 2.508907 3.954820
```

Another option is to randomly permute one of the columns.  This will result in the overall total and the row and column totals being the same as the original, but the relationship between Test1 and Test2 will now be independent.

```
> (worep <- replicate(3, {
+   tmpdat <- rawdat
+   tmpdat$Test1 <- sample(tmpdat$Test1)
+   xtabs( ~ Test1 + Test2, tmpdat)
+ }))
, , 1

     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 35 24
    F 27 14

, , 2

     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 37 22
    F 25 16

, , 3

     Test2
Test1  T  F
    T 34 25
    F 28 13

> 
> apply(worep, 3, addmargins, simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
     Test2
Test1  T  F Sum
  T   35 24  59
  F   27 14  41
  Sum 62 38 100

[[2]]
     Test2
Test1  T  F Sum
  T   37 22  59
  F   25 16  41
  Sum 62 38 100

[[3]]
     Test2
Test1  T  F Sum
  T   34 25  59
  F   28 13  41
  Sum 62 38 100

> apply(worep, 3, function(x) fisher.test(x)$estimate)
[1] 0.7582865 1.0755698 0.6343369
>
```